# Reducing data on vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I use QGIS for GIS. Lately I had just too many points appearing on my vector layer and I will want to reduce them (100 for a given scale : min-1 and max 9000). With labels it works quite well but how can this be done with the features on the vector layer in QGIS?
I will need an expression to choose at random 100 points for the layer, that is if the query builder could do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Random Selection** tool to randomly select a specified number (or percentage) of features. This can be accessed by 2 ways:

- *Vector > Research Tools > Random Selection*

[image: Method 1]

- *Processing Toolbox > Random Selection*

[image: Method 2]

I used QGIS 2.8.2-Wien. Hope this helps!

Comment: Really great. I use QGIS 2.8.1 and it works. Just to know, please Joseph is the GRASS plugin stable? I am unable to use QGIS GUI to work with GRASS.

Comment: Hmm! Is it possible to create another layer with the new selection? because it does not present quite cool!

Comment: @MrNk - GRASS works fine for me, if you have a problem with it then you should post a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) including how you are trying to use GRASS with perhaps screenshots and mention any errors you are receiving. And yes, you can create another layer with the selected features. _Right-click_ the layer **after** you run the tool, go to _Save As..._ and check the **Save only selected features**. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great! I will do just that.